# MYSQL python list index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I'm wring a web scraping program to collect data from truecar.com
my database has 3 columns
and when I run the program I get an error which is this : list indext out of range
here is what I've done so far:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# take the car's name
requested_car_name = input()

# inject the car's name into the URL

my_request = requests.get('https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/' +
                          requested_car_name + '/location-holtsville-ny/?sort[]=best_match')


my_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_request.text, 'html.parser')

# ************ car_model column in database ******************
car_model = my_soup.find_all(
    'span', attrs={'class': 'vehicle-header-make-model text-truncate'})

# we have a list of car models
car_list = []
for item in range(20):
    # appends car_model to car_list
    car_list.append(car_model[item].text)

car_string = ', '.join('?' * len(car_list))


# ************** price column in database *****************************
price = my_soup.find_all(
    'div', attrs={'data-test': 'vehicleCardPricingBlockPrice'})
price_list = []
for item in range(20):
    # appends price to price_list
    price_list.append(price[item].text)

price_string = ', '.join('?' * len(price_list))


# ************** distance column in database ***************************
distance = my_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'vehicleMileage'})
distance_list = []
for item in range(20):
    # appends distance to distance_list
    distance_list.append(distance[item].text)

distance_string = ', '.join('?' * len(distance_list))

# check the connection
print('CONNECTING ...')

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="xxxxx",
    user="xxxxxx",
    password="xxxxxx",
    port='xxxxxx',
    database='xxxxxx'
)

print('CONNECTED')

# checking the connection is done

my_cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
insert_command = 'INSERT INTO car_name (car_model, price, distance) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);' % (car_string, price_string, distance_string)
# values = (car_string, price_string, distance_string)
my_cursor.execute(insert_command, car_list, price_list, distance_list)
mydb.commit()

print(my_cursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted")

mydb.close()
```

and I have another problem that I can't insert a list into my columns and I have tried many ways but unfortunately I wasn't able to get it working

I think the problem is in this line:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4a3930bf0f57> in <module>
     23 for item in range(20):
     24     # appends car_model to car_list
---> 25     car_list.append(car_model[item].text)
     26 
     27 car_string = ', '.join('?' * len(car_list))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't want it to insert the whole list to 1 row in database . I want the first 20 car's price, model, mileage in truecar.com in my database

Comment: can you past the complete trace to show which line exactly is causing the issue?

Comment: man, could you give us traceback?

Comment: sorry I had problem with internet

Comment: change the line 25 to --- for item in range(len(car_model)):
you can't hardcode it to 20

Comment: change line 25 to what ?

Comment: I got this error : execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: I got this error too : Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya you are hard coding the length. Change how you are iterating through your soup elements. So:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# take the car's name
requested_car_name = input('Enter car name: ')

# inject the car's name into the URL

my_request = requests.get('https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/' +
                          requested_car_name + '/location-holtsville-ny/?sort[]=best_match')


my_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_request.text, 'html.parser')

# ************ car_model column in database ******************
car_model = my_soup.find_all(
    'span', attrs={'class': 'vehicle-header-make-model text-truncate'})

# we have a list of car models
car_list = []
for item in car_model:
    # appends car_model to car_list
    car_list.append(item.text)




# ************** price column in database *****************************
price = my_soup.find_all(
    'div', attrs={'data-test': 'vehicleCardPricingBlockPrice'})
price_list = []
for item in price:
    # appends price to price_list
    price_list.append(item.text)




# ************** distance column in database ***************************
distance = my_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'vehicleMileage'})
distance_list = []
for item in distance:
    # appends distance to distance_list
    distance_list.append(item.text)




# check the connection
print('CONNECTING ...')

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="xxxxx",
    user="xxxxxx",
    password="xxxxxx",
    port='xxxxxx',
    database='xxxxxx'
)

print('CONNECTED')

# checking the connection is done

my_cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
insert_command = 'INSERT INTO car_name (car_model, price, distance) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
values = list(zip(car_list, price_list, distance_list))
my_cursor.executemany(insert_command, values)
mydb.commit()

print(my_cursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted")

mydb.close()
```

**ALTERNATE:**

there's also the API where you can fetch the dat:

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
import math


# take the car's name
requested_car_name = input('Enter car name: ')

# inject the car's name into the URL

url = 'https://www.truecar.com/abp/api/vehicles/used/listings'
payload = {
'city': 'holtsville',
'collapse': 'true',
'fallback': 'true',
'include_incentives': 'true',
'include_targeted_incentives': 'true',
'make_slug': requested_car_name,
'new_or_used': 'u',
'per_page': '30',
'postal_code': '',
'search_event': 'true',
'sort[]': 'best_match',
'sponsored': 'true',
'state': 'ny',
'page':'1'}


jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
total = jsonData['total']
total_pages = math.ceil(total/30)

total_pages_input = input('There are %s pages to iterate.\nEnter the number of pages to go through or type ALL: ' %total_pages)
if total_pages_input.upper() == 'ALL':
    total_pages = total_pages
else:
    total_pages = int(total_pages_input)

values = []
for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    if page == 1:
        car_listings = jsonData['listings']
    else:
        payload.update({'page':'%s' %page})
        jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
        car_listings = jsonData['listings']
        
    for listing in car_listings:
        vehicle = listing['vehicle']
        
        ex_color = vehicle['exterior_color']
        in_color = vehicle['interior_color']
        location = vehicle['location']
        price = vehicle['list_price']
        make = vehicle['make']
        model = vehicle['model']
        mileage = vehicle['mileage']
        style = vehicle['style']
        year = vehicle['year']
        
        engine = vehicle['engine']
        accidentCount = vehicle['condition_history']['accidentCount']
        ownerCount = vehicle['condition_history']['ownerCount']
        isCleanTitle = vehicle['condition_history']['titleInfo']['isCleanTitle']
        isFrameDamaged = vehicle['condition_history']['titleInfo']['isFrameDamaged']
        isLemon = vehicle['condition_history']['titleInfo']['isLemon']
        isSalvage = vehicle['condition_history']['titleInfo']['isSalvage']
        isTheftRecovered = vehicle['condition_history']['titleInfo']['isTheftRecovered']
        
        values.append((ex_color, in_color,location,price,make,model,mileage,
        style,year,engine,accidentCount,ownerCount,isCleanTitle,isFrameDamaged,
        isLemon, isSalvage,isTheftRecovered))
    print('Completed: Page %s of %s' %(page,total_pages))
        
        
# check the connection
print('CONNECTING ...')

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="xxxxx",
    user="xxxxxx",
    password="xxxxxx",
    port='xxxxxx',
    database='xxxxxx'
)

print('CONNECTED')

# checking the connection is done

my_cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

# create_command = ''' create table car_information (exterior_color varchar(255), interior_color varchar(255),location varchar(255),price varchar(255),make varchar(255),model varchar(255),mileage varchar(255),
#         style varchar(255),year varchar(255),engine varchar(255),accidentCount varchar(255),ownerCount varchar(255),isCleanTitle varchar(255),isFrameDamaged varchar(255),
#         isLemon varchar(255), isSalvage varchar(255),isTheftRecovered varchar(255))'''

# my_cursor.execute(create_command)
# print('created')


insert_command = '''INSERT INTO car_name (exterior_color, interior_color,location,price,make,model,mileage,
        style,year,engine,accidentCount,ownerCount,isCleanTitle,isFrameDamaged,
        isLemon, isSalvage,isTheftRecovered) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
my_cursor.executemany(insert_command, values)
mydb.commit()

print(my_cursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted")

mydb.close()
```

Comment: I got this error with your changes : ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Sorry. Had a typo. Fixed it above

Comment: it gives me question mark in database same as Raphael Eckert's answer

Comment: well you're joining the strings with `car_string = ', '.join('?' * len(car_list))` I edited my solution

Comment: Data too long for column 'car_model' at row 1

Comment: ok, so what should be entered in each row? is row 1 be something like: `BMW X5, $30,480,  39,078 miles`?

Comment: @Mehran, give the code i edited above. See if that works (I don't have mysql installed to test it)

Comment: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: do you mean the previous code you wrote ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228849/discussion-between-chitown88-and-mehran).

Comment: @Mehran go to the chat.

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be that the list of car models has less than 20 entries.

```
for item in range(20):
  car_list.append(car_model[item].text)
```

this always tries to append exactly 20 items to the car list. if you have less than 20 entries, there is an error, because car_model[20].text does not exist when there are only 10 entries. you can try

```
for item in range(len(car_model)):
  car_list.append(car_model[item].text)
```

Comment: in database it is all question marks like this =>  5 ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?

Comment: can you print(car_model) right after you pull it from the db, to see what acually got pulled?

Comment: I entered bmw and it gave me 1 Record Inserted and in database I have this: '6', '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?', '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?', '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?'

Comment: I don't want it to insert the whole list to 1 row in database . I want the first 20 car's price, model, mileage in truecar.com in my database

Comment: "can you print(car_model) right after you pull it from the db, to see what acually got pulled?" can you still do this. I am not talking about inserting, i am talking about the format and content of this secific variable right before the appending.

Comment: it gave me an empty list , you mean this ?

Comment: yep. but it seems you figured it out already